# How to reduce the Font of a text in LWUIT TextArea

Tags: java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I have created LWUIT `TextArea`,and I have added paragraphs of text to my `TextArea` ,now i want to reduce my `TextArea`'s font size,I have used the code below:

```
TextArea big = new TextArea(detailNews.getDescription());
Font createSystemFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_ITALIC, Font.SIZE_SMALL);
    big.getStyle().setFont(createSystemFont);
    big.setEditable(false);                    
    form2.addComponent(big);
    form2.show();
```

But, why I am not able to reduce the font of my text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
TextArea big = new TextArea(detailNews.getDescription());

Font createSystemFont = Font.createSystemFont(Font.FACE_SYSTEM, Font.STYLE_ITALIC,Font.SIZE_SMALL);

big.getUnselectedStyle().setFont(createSystemFont); 
big.getSelectedStyle().setFont(createSystemFont); 

// Added TextArea object big to the Form object form.
form.addComponent(big);
form.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Create font in Resource editor**. Then, import the font from resource file in your app. By using this method, you can apply any font to your app that is installed in your system. You can also set any font size to the font.

Explore the link to know how to create font in resource editor.

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cjbcgcdd.html#z400088e1296018